# Spectrogram plotting using QWT and FFTW

Tags: qt, fft, qwt

Can anyone provide me some help in spectrogram plotting using QWt. 
I want to plot spectrogram of my FFT data that I am calculating using FFTW.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As general propose of plotting using `qwt` this robust library provide plenty of examples for beginners.
Brief explanations of using this library for a spectrogram is to use `QwtPlotSpectrogram` class and set `RenderThreadCount` and `setCachePolicy` for performance also you should provide a color map implement `QwtColorMap` and for data `QwtRasterData`. you can see [spectrogram example](https://github.com/eiimage/qwt/tree/master/examples/spectrogram) under examples folder a deep look would be a nice start point for beginner.